# asp.net core editor template: Property name null

Tags: asp.net, razor, mvc-editor-templates

I have several editor templates in which appears the same code for rendering an Enum like in this example:

```
@model OriginDto

@* This div is what I want to move to a specific editor template *@
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Kind" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Kind" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Origin.KindOfOrigin>()"  class="form-control">    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Kind" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Source" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Source" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Source" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="EntryDate"></label>
    <input asp-for="EntryDate" class="form-control" type="date" />
    <span asp-validation-for="EntryDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

So I decided to create the following template editor for Enum:

```
@model Enum
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="@Model" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList(Model.GetType())" class="form-control"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

And replace the previous div with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Kind)
```

But when it renders the HTML there are some differences. For example, the label is empty:

```
<label class="control-label" for="Cpu_Origin_Kind"></label>
```

But in the original template it had the property name:

```
<label class="control-label" for="Cpu_Origin_Kind">Kind</label>
```

It seems like the property name its not reaching the template. In fact, when examining "this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" while debugging the template it is null.

My questions are:

1. Why the property name is not reaching this template?
2. Is this approach wrong? If so, any hint is welcome.

Comment: Seems that changing `@model Enum` with `@model dynamic` solves the problem, but an explanation is most welcome.